# Teen Sci-Fi book probably from 80's possibly early 90's - aliens help a teenager on Earth

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I can't remember much about the book.  I read it when I was in middle school.  What I do remember is that a human kid finds these tiny aliens - one of which can stop/slow time.  The one scene that sticks out in my memory is a bully trying to punch the kid, and the alien stops or slows down time enough that the kid has time to easily dodge the punch.  Honestly can't remember much more from the book.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book you're looking for is "Aliens Ate My Homework" by Bruce Coville.  It was published in 1993 and is the first book in the Rod Allbright series.  It was followed by "I Left My Sneakers in Dimension X", "The Search for Snout", and "Aliens Stole My Body".

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been thinking about that book on and off for years, and didn't know how to find it until I stumbled upon this site.